# Given PC=0x32011C, a value is located in 0x32010C, then what's the offset?

Tags: assembly, memory-address, riscv

I wonder if address offset could be negative.
For example, is the answer to my question negative 16 bytes?

Comment: Yes, offsets are typically signed. You can use an assembler to test it, or read the manual of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably best to speak about offsets in specific instructions, such as a conditional branches or call instructions.

In RISC V, many instructions have a 12-bit offset, and these are all signed extended to 32- or 64-bits (for RV32 or RV64, respectively).  (Some instructions have a 20-bit offset, some of which work a bit differently.)

The PC of the instruction doing the pc-relative addressing is the base value, which is added to an offset — that means an offset of 0 refers to the currently executing instruction, +4 the succeeding 32-bit instruction and -4 the preceding 32-bit instruction (in memory by address, not necessarily in execution order).

In order to support the compact format instructions (16-bit) and extended instruction sizes (48-bits and larger), the offset for instructions that do pc-relative addressing provides for even byte-offset values — since the value is always even, the low bit is always zero, and hence it is not encoded in the offset.  So, the offset encoded in such instructions is padded with one zero bit at the low end (as the LSB) before use by the hardware.